# Zend Framework Routing issues

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I just got the Rob Allen's Album Rest tutorial working on my windows machine with sql server.

I can see all the albums show up on my screen. But when i click on the edit,delete,add links i get a "Not Found" error and it says

```
The requested URL /zf2-tutorial/public/album/edit/1 was not found on this server.
```

Am i doing something wrong here. My first guess is that i have not set vhosts, so it can be the problem. But this works just fine on my mac without any issues.

Also, as a little background. There is an IIS server running on port 80 and Zend server running on port 81.

Would this be an issue again ?

Comment: show the full URL that's not working.

Comment: http://localhost:81/zf2-tutorial/public/ ----------> works and this http://localhost:81/zf2-tutorial/public/album -----------> doesnt work. anything for that matter */album/edit/4 or */album/delete/3 doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, all i had to do was change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All for .htaccess in my httpd.conf

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/overview.html